# Load HTML content from URL AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate PDF from the HTML I generate using angularjs but when I use the angular URL to request (via [requestify](https://github.com/ranm8/requestify)) instead the content of the page, I'm getting the content of `index.html` page...does anyone know how to get the HTML content generate on the `ng-view`

`$routeProvider
      .when('/mediakit/:account', {
        templateUrl: 'app/mediakit/mediakit.html',
        controller: 'MediaKitCtrl'
      });`

I want the content from `http://localhost:9000/mediakit/accountid` that uses `mediakit.html` as template not the content of index.html (where the contents are load through `ng-view`)

The code I'm using to generate PDF

```
    let pdf = require('html-pdf');
      let requestify = require('requestify');
      let outputPath = './server/public/';
      //req.body.mediaKitURL --> is the URL that I load the content when I open in the browser
      requestify.get(req.body.mediaKitURL).then(function (response) {
        // Get the raw HTML response body
        let html = response.body; --> //the content here is the content from index.html, 
      //I would like to get the content from the my angular route that uses mediakit.html (same when I open the URL in the browser)
        let config = {format: 'letter'}; 

    // Create the PDF
        pdf.create(html, config).toFile(outputPath + '/media_kit_'+req.params.account+'.pdf', function (err, result) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log(result); // { filename: '/pathtooutput/generated.pdf' }
          res.status(200).json();
        });
      });
```

I hope that's clear...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for pdf viewer to show generated pdf file content.

for that,plz refere below angularjs directive,

https://github.com/legalthings/angular-pdfjs-viewer

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for.